# How to permute a dataframe columnwise with paird colume in R?

Tags: r, permutation

So I have a dataframe (dataframe1)  with 4 columns and 5 rows like :

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4
R1  a   1   15   8
R2  b   0   30   5
R3  c   1   10   2
R4  d   0   27   1
R5  e   1   39   4
```

How can I permute the C2 and C3 and pair them together?

like:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4
R1  a   0   27   8
R2  b   0   30   5
R3  c   1   10   2
R4  d   1   39   1
R5  e   1   15   4
```

permute the C2 and C3 columns but let C2 and C3 maintain paired.

Is that posible?

I try `sample()` but I can't find any code to permute while pair columns.

PS: I don't want any change from C1 and C4 while permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the `sample` on the sequence of rows, and use that as row index to modify the values of 'C2', 'C3'

```
i1 <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df1)))
df1[c("C2", "C3")] <- df1[i1, c("C2", "C3")]
```

-output

```
df1
#   C1 C2 C3 C4
#R1  a  0 27  8
#R2  b  1 15  5
#R3  c  1 39  2
#R4  d  0 30  1
#R5  e  1 10  4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(C1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), C2 = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L), C3 = c(15L, 30L, 10L, 27L, 39L), C4 = c(8L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("R1", "R2", 
"R3", "R4", "R5"))
```